# Remove NaN from lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have converted data frame rows to lists and in those list there are NaN values which I would like to remove.
This is my attempt but the NaN values are not removed

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('MainFile.xlsx', dtype = str)
df_list = df.values.tolist()
print(df_list)
print('=' * 50)

for l in df_list:
    newlist = [x for x in l if x != 'nan']
    print(newlist)
```

Here's a snapshot of the original data
[image]

I could find a solution using these lines (but I welcome any ideas)

```
for l in df_list:
    newlist = [x for x in l if x == x]
    print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not working because you are trying to compare it to string 'nan'.

If excel cell is empty it is returned as `NaN` value in pandas.

You can use numpy library, to compare it with `NaN`:

```
import numpy as np

for l in df_list:
    newlist = [x for x in l if x != np.nan]
    print(newlist)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get all values from the dataframe, which are not `NaN`, you can just do:

```
df.stack().tolist()
```

If you want to print values with the loop (as in your example), you can do:

```
for l in df.columns:
    print(list(df[l][df[l].notna()]))
```

To create nested list with a loop:

```
main = []

for l in df.T.columns:
    new_list = list(df.T[l][df.T[l].notna()])
    main.append(new_list)
    
print(main)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but this doesn't work on my side (may be because the data is of string type, not numbers. I am not sure). This worked for me `[x for x in l if x == x]`

Comment: Please look at the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When used `df.stack().tolist()` I got one list only for the whole dataframe and the main target for me is get one list and this list has lists for each row within the dataframe.

Comment: I've added solution for creating nested list with a loop for all not nan values.

Comment: Oh sorry. This produces lists of columns not rows!!

Comment: Then you can do the same for transposed dataframe. Please look at the last loop after changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try the approach that is proposed [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/remove-nan-from-list-python/#:%7E:text=The%20NaN%20value%20in%20programming,the%20list%20in%20this%20tutorial.):

```
import numpy as np

newlist = [x for x in df_list if np.isnan(x) == False]
print(newlist)
```

I hope that this will help.

Comment: Thanks. This raises an error `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`. Note that I have the dataframe as string not as flaot or integers